# 2D rotation of an object along a custom axis

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to rotate a 2d object around/onto a custom axis. The desired results is for the transparent rectangle rotate using the red dot as a pivot point.

[image]

**Edit:**

The following code from the selected answer works, but I had to put the rotation before the placement for it to work, so adding the code here for future readers:

```
    Call Rotate_Object_About_Axis(objBookcaseB, objHinge, Range("rotation").Value)
End Sub

Private Sub Rotate_Object_About_Axis(RotObj As Shape, AxisObj As Shape, R_Deg As Double)

    Dim RotLoc1 As Coordinates
    Dim RotLoc2 As Coordinates
    Dim AxisLoc As Coordinates
    Dim R_Rad As Double
    Dim Pi As Double
    
    Pi = 3.14159
    R_Rad = (R_Deg / 360 * (2 * Pi))
    Debug.Print R_Rad
    Debug.Print R_Deg
    
    
    AxisLoc = ObjectLocation(AxisObj)
    RotLoc1 = ObjectLocation(RotObj)
    
    RotLoc2 = RotateCoordinates(AxisLoc.X, AxisLoc.Y, RotLoc1.X, RotLoc1.Y, R_Rad)
    With RotObj
        .Rotation = .Rotation + (R_Rad * 360 / (2 * Pi))
        .Left = RotLoc2.X - (.Width / 2) 'This needs to be after the rotation
        .Top = RotLoc2.Y - (.Height / 2) 'This needs to be after the rotation
    End With
    
End Sub
Private Function ObjectLocation(Shp As Object) As Coordinates
    ObjectLocation.X = Shp.Left + (Shp.Width / 2)
    ObjectLocation.Y = Shp.Top + (Shp.Height / 2)
End Function
Private Function RotateCoordinates(Xa, Ya, X, Y, R) As Coordinates
    RotateCoordinates.X = ((X - Xa) * Cos(R)) - ((Y - Ya) * Sin(R)) + Xa
    RotateCoordinates.Y = ((X - Xa) * Sin(R)) + ((Y - Ya) * Cos(R)) + Ya
End Function
```

Comment: Convert to polar coordinates, then it's easy.

Comment: @SimonGoater I'm not familiar with polar coordinates. I'll try to look it up, but so far it doesn't seem that easy :-\ (considering the level at which I am asking the question)

Comment: Well for the most part it won't matter, just type in the formula then use it as much as you want. While polar coordinates may be more applicable in a lot of 2D programming situations, I think here, you're just going to need to convert the value back to Cartesian Coordinates in order to move the object.

Comment: Oh, What are you making? This looks like fun!

Comment: @CameronCritchlowA tool to calculate the best linear actuator & placement to use for hidden bookshelves to open at a specific angle. Strangely, I nailed the line intersecting circle and circle intersecting circle part that comes after, but I'm struggling with ... well VBA is a pain for one, but the rotation for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Original:**

---

Well I can see we already have the general answer, but I had a bit of fun making this so I'll post it anyway.
It shows how all the concepts come together so Might help someone.

```
Option Explicit
Type ObjLocData
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type
Sub Rotate_Object_About_Axis()

    Dim RotObj As Shape
    Dim RotLoc1 As ObjLocData
    Dim RotLoc2 As ObjLocData
    Dim AxisObj As Shape
    Dim AxisLoc As ObjLocData
    Dim R_Rad As Double
    Dim Pi As Double
    
    R_Rad = 0.1
    Pi = 3.14159
    
    Set AxisObj = ActiveSheet.Shapes("AxisObj")
    AxisLoc = ObjectLocation(AxisObj)
    Set RotObj = ActiveSheet.Shapes("RotObj")
    RotLoc1 = ObjectLocation(RotObj)
    Debug.Print AxisLoc.X
    
    RotLoc2 = RotateCoordinates(AxisLoc.X, AxisLoc.Y, RotLoc1.X, RotLoc1.Y, R_Rad)
    With RotObj
        .Left = RotLoc2.X - (.Width / 2)
        .Top = RotLoc2.Y - (.Height / 2)
        .Rotation = .Rotation + (R_Rad * 360 / (2 * Pi))
    End With
    
End Sub
Function ObjectLocation(Shp As Object) As ObjLocData
    ObjectLocation.X = Shp.Left + (Shp.Width / 2)
    ObjectLocation.Y = Shp.Top + (Shp.Height / 2)
End Function
Function RotateCoordinates(Xa, Ya, X, Y, R) As ObjLocData
    RotateCoordinates.X = ((X - Xa) * Cos(R)) - ((Y - Ya) * Sin(R)) + Xa
    RotateCoordinates.Y = ((X - Xa) * Sin(R)) + ((Y - Ya) * Cos(R)) + Ya
End Function
'Location Formulas
'X'=(x-p)cos(?)-(y-q)sin(?)+p,
'y'=(x-p)sin(?)+(y-q)cos(?)+q.
```

### **Update:**

---

I'm redone the script to work with degrees, and to just be a stand alone sub. you just call it with your two shapes and required rotation in degrees. Please remember **the axis of rotation will be the center of the pivot object** if you want it to be anything else, you will need to change the code.

```
Option Explicit
Type ObjLocData
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type
Sub Example_Of_Usage()

    Dim Door As Shape
    Dim Pivot As Shape
    Dim R As Double
    
    Set Door = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Door")
    Set Pivot = ActiveSheet.Shapes("PivotPoint")
    R = 45
    
    Call Rotate_Object_About_Axis(Door, Pivot, R)
    
End Sub
Sub Rotate_Object_About_Axis(RotObj As Shape, AxisObj As Shape, R_Deg As Double)

    Dim RotLoc1 As ObjLocData
    Dim RotLoc2 As ObjLocData
    Dim AxisLoc As ObjLocData
    Dim R_Rad As Double
    Dim Pi As Double
    
    Pi = 3.14159
    R_Rad = (R_Deg / 360 * (2 * Pi))
    Debug.Print R_Rad
    Debug.Print R_Deg
    
    
    AxisLoc = ObjectLocation(AxisObj)
    RotLoc1 = ObjectLocation(RotObj)
    
    RotLoc2 = RotateCoordinates(AxisLoc.X, AxisLoc.Y, RotLoc1.X, RotLoc1.Y, R_Rad)
    With RotObj
        .Left = RotLoc2.X - (.Width / 2)
        .Top = RotLoc2.Y - (.Height / 2)
        .Rotation = .Rotation + (R_Rad * 360 / (2 * Pi))
    End With
    
End Sub
Function ObjectLocation(Shp As Object) As ObjLocData
    ObjectLocation.X = Shp.Left + (Shp.Width / 2)
    ObjectLocation.Y = Shp.Top + (Shp.Height / 2)
End Function
Function RotateCoordinates(Xa, Ya, X, Y, R) As ObjLocData
    RotateCoordinates.X = ((X - Xa) * Cos(R)) - ((Y - Ya) * Sin(R)) + Xa
    RotateCoordinates.Y = ((X - Xa) * Sin(R)) + ((Y - Ya) * Cos(R)) + Ya
End Function
'Location Formulas
'X'=(x-p)cos(?)-(y-q)sin(?)+p,
'y'=(x-p)sin(?)+(y-q)cos(?)+q.
```

### **New Example:**

---

[image]

Comment: Oh my lord I looked at the images being so confused, why are you showing me with arrows the circle is rotating; it's not even rotating. Oh wait, the arrow is rotating around the circle! Haha

Comment: Yeah, Sorry, The circle is my pivot object, you could use any method to define a pivot point, this is just pretty easy. The arrow with rotate around wherever you place the pivot.

Comment: @FMaz008 , Sometimes I forget not everyone can just see what I was thinking

Comment: I have tried to implement your function, but it seems to have an issue. I have added the code and a screenshot to the question. (Note that the 2 answers lead to the exact same results.)

Comment: Okay, I have some other work to do, then I'll review your changes

Comment: Okay, See above. Just remember, if your object hits a "Wall" it won't rotate beyond

Comment: Maybe my visual examples are not clear. In yours, the blue is the bookcase being in closed position. In yellow, the *same* bookcase in the open position. The pivot point is where the pivot hinge is located, so it should remain at the same relative location on both shapes.

Comment: I added an image of the desired results to clarify the issue

Comment: I added an image of the expected results to clarify the solution. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251527/discussion-between-cameron-critchlow-and-fmaz008).

Comment: The code itself works so long as you set the Left and Top after the rotation, and so long as the original shape is at least its own width from the left, and its own height from the top. (separate question created)

The examples provided seems wrong (because the position is set before the rotation). If you fix the code and correct of remove the images, I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I made all the rotations/translations seen with my code. I'm not having the same issues.

Answer (score 3):

The common approach to this to divide the operation in three basic steps:

1. move the object to the local space (also called object space)
2. rotate around the origin
3. move the object back (also called world space)

   ```
    function rotate(obj, axisX, axisY, angle) {
        // 1.
        obj.x -= axisX
        obj.y -= axisY

        // 2.
        obj.rotate(angle)

        // 3.
        obj.x += axisX
        obj.y += axisY
    }
   ```

**Edit** some notes on `obj.rotate`: the approach assumes that the `rotate` function rotates globally (world space) that is, if the object is not at the origin, it will be rotated in a orbit like fashion. But if `rotate` rotates the object locally (object space) the object will always be rotated around its center, regardless where it is in world space. In this case, you need to additionally compute the new position yourself (but with the same principle):

```
ox = obj.x - axisX
oy = obj.y - axisY

// apply 2D rotation matrix
obj.x = ox * cos(angle) - oy * sin(angle)
obj.y = ox * sin(angle) + oy * cos(angle)

obj.x += axisX
obj.y += axisY
```

Comment: `obj` might have a `translate` method that encapsulates the movement along a given vector.

Comment: So if the rotation method rotate around the middle, first move the object of the difference between the desired rotation axis and the default axis, rotate, and do the same movement in reverse?

Comment: @FMaz008 I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @taiyo I tried to implement your algorith, but I'm struggling with the placement. I edited my question to put the code I tried.

Comment: @FMaz008 can you show a screenshot of the placements (before and after)?

Comment: I basically loose the original position. The original Left and Top is missing. Otherwise the formula seems to calculate the translation from the rotation properly

Comment: @taiyo I uploaded an image to the post

Comment: @FMaz008 I dont understand what "Left and Top is missing" means. But it seems you use `Obj.Left` and `Obj.Top` as the pivot for the object rotation.Try to use the center of the object, something like `deltaX = Obj.Left + Obj.Width / 2 - Axis.X` and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251507/discussion-between-fmaz008-and-taiyo).

Answer (score 2):

I had written code in VBA for PowerPoint to create a rotational pattern of shapes and this includes the following code that does what you are asking for.

Recognize that a rotation about an arbitrary point is decomposed into a translation of the shape into the pivot, then a rotation and then the reverse translation.

In concept this is `(offset) + [rotate] ( (point)-(offset) )`

Here `pat` is the shape to be rotated, `t` is the rotation (in degrees) that I want to set. The rotation center is defined by coordinates `x_c` and `y_c`.

```
pat.Rotation = pat.Rotation + t
x_i = pat.Left + pat.Width / 2
y_i = pat.Top + pat.Height / 2

x_f = x_c + (x_i - x_c) * Cos(t * DEG_TO_RAD) - (y_i - y_c) * Sin(t * DEG_TO_RAD)
y_f = y_c + (x_i - x_c) * Sin(t * DEG_TO_RAD) + (y_i - y_c) * Cos(t * DEG_TO_RAD)

pat.Left = pat.Left + (x_f - x_i)
pat.Top = pat.Top + (y_f - y_i)
```

In the end `pat.Left`, `pat.Top` and `pat.Rotation` describe the position and orientation of the shape after the rotation about the arbitrary point `(x_c, y_c)` by the angle `t`.

Here is a visual example of my rotational pattern code

[image: fig]

How does it work?

Note that the position and orientation of ashape is given by the following parameters

[image: fig2]

You see that `Height` and `Width` do not correspond to the geometry of the shape but that of the bounding box (gray dashed box). The same for the location given by `Left` and `Top`. Also, the rotation is given as positive in a clockwise fashion in degrees.

So the math here represents, going from the position parameters above, to the geometry (shape center), applying the rotation about the center and going back to the position parameters.

---

Note the following header is needed in a module to define some constants.

```
Public Const PI As Double = 3.14159265358979
Public Const DEG_TO_RAD As Double = PI / 180#
Public Const RAD_TO_DEG As Double = 180# / PI
```

Comment: Does your code works if you start with the vertical original shape and the center shape 20 pixels from the left and try to rotate the other way?

Pretty sure my issue has to do with the edge of the sheet for some reasons, as the resulting shape I get has a Left value of 0 while being too far right

Comment: @FMaz008 - yes it works fine past the edges of the page left-right-top-bottom.